# Bootstrap 4 - How to float a div on the right of Cards?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to put a `div` on the side of the cards, i tried to put a `div` on the cards `<div class="col-lg-8">` and a `col-lg-4` on the `div` that should float on the right of cards, but when i add the `col-lg-8` and `col-lg-4` the cards lose the inline layout, and the the `div` that should float on the right, does not appear.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-8">
      <div class="col-3">

        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/750x325" alt="Card image cap">
          <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="col-3">

        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/750x325" alt="Card image cap">
          <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="col-3">

        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/750x325" alt="Card image cap">
          <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="col-3">

        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/750x325" alt="Card image cap">
          <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="col-3">

        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/750x325" alt="Card image cap">
          <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="col-3">

        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/750x325" alt="Card image cap">
          <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color: blue">
      
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

How it should be:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given block of code was

```
 <div class="col-4">
        <div class="card">
             <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/750x325" alt="Card image cap">
        <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
       </div>
    </div>
```

In order to match the requirements, I added **float-left** class to `<div class="col-4">`.

The div to the right with blue background was also rendered.